# ios get clipboard generalPasteboard full history

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipasteboard

Is this possible in iOS to get full history of clipboard ...

Means get whatever user copied on clipboard, full log of content..

I know we can get last content from `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]` but is there way to get full log or previous content from clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can access pasteboard items directly:

```
for item in UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().items {
    print(item)
}
```

Comment: That's rather not possible in iOS.